# There are 4 slots but I have 3 blue cubes. How do I open this door in 'The Final Hurdle'?

Tags: antichamber

In Antichamber, one of the first puzzles with the blue gun involves 4 slots, but I have only seen 3 blue cubes on this floor. How do I proceed to open this door?

[image: Three cubes, four slots]

Comment: What room is this in?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The grate thing right in front of you is an elevator/trampoline thing. If you jump on it and time your jumps right, you will reach the bottom.
[image]

When you do, use one of your cubes to hold it down.
[image]

Then walk into the room at the bottom. There will be a door that requires 2 cubes to open, and will have a cube behind it.

[image]

Once you get that cube and retrieve the ones you used to open the door, get back on the elevator and remove the cube that is holding it down. Then you will be back where you started with 4 cubes.

Comment: *"If you jump on it and time your jumps right, you will reach the bottom"* - You don't need good timing when you have two cubes.  Just jump, aim downwards, and shoot a cube at the elevator after you land.  Jump again, shoot another cube, and pick up your first one.  Repeat until you reach the bottom.

Comment: Yeah, that works too.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft you can actually do this on elevators with just one cube - it simply takes better timing to suck it up on the way down to replace it at the bottom. Doesn't help with this puzzle though... (why yes, I did do this with one cube, get to the bottom and get myself stuck. Why d'you ask...)