# How do I get through The Final Hurdle with 3 cubes?

Tags: antichamber

How do I get through the room *The Final Hurdle* to the point pictured with all 3 cubes?

[image: Three cubes, four slots]

(picture taken from [There are 4 slots but I have 3 blue cubes. How do I open this door in 'The Final Hurdle'?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/103457/there-are-4-slots-but-i-have-3-blue-cubes-how-do-i-open-this-door/103510#103510))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, put one cube in the slot that opens the first door
[image: First slot]
Then walk through the laser that opens the red doors
[image: Red door laser]
Next, block off the other laser with the two blocks you have
[image: Second laser blocked off]
Then, walk past and take both blocks
[image: Past the laser with both blocks]
Use one block to prop up the last door
[image: Propped up door]
Use the other block to jump over the laser that you previously blocked off
[image: Laser jumping block]
After you are past the laser, grab the block and use it to prop up the first door
[image: Other propped up door]
Then grab the first block, and run back through, grabbing each block as you pass it.
[image]
[image]
[image]
**Success!**